# How to preview email templates of Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, email, templates, woocommerce

I can't seem to find an option to preview the different e-mail templates of Woocommerce. In the admin section of Woocommerce there is a link to preview the "Order recieved" email for customers. But I would like to edit and preview the "Order recieved" email sent to the admin.

I have tried WP Better emails plugin and the WP email template plugins but they didn't offer a preview button for all the different emails of Woocommerce.

Previewing the email templates by placing orders isn't an option because there's a lag of ten minutes between placing the order and recieving the admin email.

Answer (score 11):

I ended up creating a small function which is executed via the admin-ajax.php script, e.g.

```
https://example.org/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=previewemail&file=emails/customer-processing-order.php&order=180
```

The function:

- sets the global `$order` variable to the order with the id specified in the `order` parameter
- load the email template specified in the `file` parameter.

This is the code (you must add it a new plug-in or in some existing php):

```
/**
 * Open a preview e-mail.
 *
 * @return null
 */
function preview_email()
{
    global $order;

    $filename = $_GET['file'];
    $orderId  = $_GET['order'];

    $order    = new WC_Order($orderId);

    include $filename;

    return null;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_previewemail', 'preview_email');
```

Comment: Nice solution...
I've altered your method a bit: also checks if you're logged in as admin, adds the email header and footer (must be because a Woocommerce update).

`function previewEmail() {
 if (is_admin()) {
  global $order;
  $sBaseDir = get_template_directory().'/woocommerce/emails/';
  $order = new WC_Order($_GET['order']);
  include $sBaseDir.'email-header.php';
  include $sBaseDir.$_GET['file'];
  include $sBaseDir.'email-footer.php';
 }
 return null;
}`

Comment: @David Riccitelli - what do you mean by "some existing php?"  I don't want to have to create a new plugin just for this and I'm not sure what you mean that you can just add it to some existing PHP.

Comment: @thecommonthread you can add the above to any PHP file which is loaded by WordPress (also a theme file would work)

Comment: I have a template file which contains woocommerce hooks and some other contents. The preview shows content of the file as per the above code. But the hooks are not executed. Any thoughts ?

Comment: if by hooks you mean shortcodes you could buffer the the output and then call do_shortcode on it (ob_start(); ... ob_get_contents(); ... ).

Comment: How can I modify this snippet to preview Email types such as processing order, completed order etc

Answer (score 8):

Modified version of the above answer using built in woo functions. The benefit is that it will look in both your theme and the default plugins template path.

```
/**
 * Open a preview e-mail.
 *
 * @return null
 */
function previewEmail() {

    if (is_admin()) {
        $default_path = WC()->plugin_path() . '/templates/';

        $files = scandir($default_path . 'emails');
        $exclude = array( '.', '..', 'email-header.php', 'email-footer.php','plain' );
        $list = array_diff($files,$exclude);
        ?><form method="get" action="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php">
<input type="hidden" name="order" value="2055">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="previewemail">
        <select name="file">
        <?php
        foreach( $list as $item ){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $item; ?>"><?php echo str_replace('.php', '', $item); ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
        </select><input type="submit" value="Go"></form><?php
        global $order;
        $order = new WC_Order($_GET['order']);
        wc_get_template( 'emails/email-header.php', array( 'order' => $order ) );


        wc_get_template( 'emails/'.$_GET['file'], array( 'order' => $order ) );
        wc_get_template( 'emails/email-footer.php', array( 'order' => $order ) );

    }
    return null; 
}

add_action('wp_ajax_previewemail', 'previewEmail');
```

Comment: Nice drrobotnik. I created a gist expanding on this to grab the available emails from the `$woocommerce->mailer` object and to apply inline styling, like WooCommerce does to actual outgoing emails. See https://gist.github.com/zlove/3b9b6a611715ec3a8a60

Comment: @drrobotnik: Does this still work in latest WooCommerce (currently 2.4.5)? The result is not what I expected, so I am wondering if it's just that this script is no longer functioning correctly, or whether it's an issue with my templates.

Comment: @inspiredlife. I wouldn't rely on code snippets without the expectation of a little tweaking. Looking at the Woo changelog, I think there have been significant changes and it might not work anymore. When I posted this, it wasn't perfect. I do hope that this pointed some folks in the right direction.

Answer (score 6):

I've come up with a solution(plugin)  that may fit your needs, although it only works with the default available email-templates this is due to the nature of how WooCommerce is managing emails. [Github](https://github.com/digamber89/woocommerce-preview-emails)

[WordPress Repo](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-preview-emails/)